# mysql variable as table name in SQL script

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I need to have a declared variable in a sql script and then use that variable as a name of the table for the subsequent script:

```
set @t := 'table1';

select * from @t as t1 
where (select count(*) from @t t2 
where t2.name = t1.name) > 1
and exists (select * from @t t3 where t3.name = t1.name and t3.HU > t1.HU)
order by name asc;
```

How would I do this. The way I described doesn't work. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Be aware that using variable table names may leave you prone to SQL injection.  How does your example not work?  What is the error?  I can see you are missing a from in the last select

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html and search for mysql dynamic sql.